# diskpart cannot delete D: partition

Tags: windows, partitioning, windows-10, diskpart

When trying to delete D: partition (C: containing system, select volume 1 + delete volume override) I get error from diskpart:

```
Delete is not allowed on the current boot, system, pagefile,crashdump or hibernation volume.
```

While the partition is represented as Healthy (no system, active, page file, etc. indicators in disk management console) I don't care too much for the reason. Is there any way to delete this partition from command line while windows is running (using diskpart or any other tool)? I don't care for the change to be visible immediately as next command in my script is shutdown. The only thing I am trying to accomplish here is to prevent the need to boot in Linux to do a simple operation of removing a partition.

Comment: The complete output of diskpart would be useful.

Comment: try to use PowerShell instead of diskpart. Run: Remove-Partition -DriveLetter D

Comment: @Strepsils since I don't have a drive letter assigned to the partition I want to delete, I tried running `Remove-Partition -DiskNumber 0 -PartitionNumber 2` on PowerShell, but I got the following error: **The operation is not allowed on a system or critical partition.** (and no, the partition is not a system nor a critical partition)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and neither `diskpart` nor Power Shell `Remove-Partition` worked.

I was able to remove the partition using [MiniTool Partition Wizard](https://www.partitionwizard.com/free-partition-manager.html).

Comment: This was downvoted but this software actually fixed this problem for me just now.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. In my case, it was caused by a paging file being manually configured on the D: partition. After removing the paging file and rebooting, `Remove-Partition` ran without issue in PowerShell.

Answer (score 1):

Turn off your computer then put it into recovery mode I have an hp note book which means I push f10 on boot then go to advanced then command prompt then type diskpart then type select disk 0 then type clean success done

Answer (score 0):

None of these 2 answers work for me. I spent hours on this and the best and one-shot solution for this is to:

Install a Windows PE on your USB and boot from USB. Then launch a terminal/prompt there and use `diskpart` as the OP mentioned to delete anything you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
  Select disk <whatever>
  offline disk
  online disk
  attribute disk clear readonly
  select partition <whatever>
  delete partition override
```